Can I rely on how new[] typically works?
Reading:
Scalar `new T` vs array `new T[1]`
the accepted answer suggests that new T[n] acts as follows (ignoring alignment and the case of n = 0):

If n = 1 or a T is trivially-destructible:

allocates sizeof(T) bytes
calls the ctor of T on the allocated memory (like placement-new)


If n > 1:

allocates sizeof(size_t + n * sizeof(T)) bytes
sets the first size_t bytes to the value of n
calls the the ctor of T on each of the n following sequences of sizeof(T) bytes (like placement new in a loop)



Can I rely on this? That is, if I emulate new T[n] in my own code as per the above, then pass the result to a delete[] - will that be well-defined and safe?
 Related question: Can I dynamically generate a contiguous sequence of non-default-ctorable objects which can be deleted with delete[]?

new T[1] and new T[N] will do the same thing (store the number of elements [usually just before the array elements] ) as delete[] needs to work the same in both cases.

@RichardCritten: Let's ignore the edge case of n = 0, I'm not actually interested in it for this question. Also, you said "do the same" - but is it guaranteed that they will do exactly this and nothing else? Not store other meta-data, for example? Or possibly store nothing at all? And maybe they might use some other allocation facility, that's fundamentally different than single-object new?

The Standard just specifies what has to happen not how it is implemented.  Under the "as-if" rule,  the runtime could ask you to write the value (number of elements) on paper and provide it later.  You will need to check your implementation, however most just store the number of elements in the bytes before the returned array address,

new T[N] allocates sizeof(T) * N + unspecified_y with unspecifed_y mainly to store N for deallocation (possibly omitted for trivial T. So "emulation" requires to know excatly what does your current compiler (which might change between version).

"will that be well-defined and safe?" I would say no. if you want emulation, allocate/deallocate block of memory, and do your placement new and call ~T manually (roughly what does std::vector)

@Jarod42: Is that the reason why std::vector can't be constructed by passing it an array of allocated memory and a size?

I think it is mostly a design choice that a limitation. But passed buffer would need to be compatible with Allocator which cannot be guaranteed.

As an implementation detail, if the heap manager for new[]/delete[] keeps a table of allocated pointer-and-size chunks, and then you pass in your own cobbled together pointer to delete[], and the heap manager cannot find that pointer in its allocated pointer-and-size table... hello std::abort.

@Eljay: Why should that even be a thing? i.e. why should a heap manager know about arrays, as opposed to merely knowing about allocated regions?

It's a thing because it's an implementation detail.  My compiler has three memory arenas:  one for malloc/free, one for new/delete, and one for new[]/delete[].  It's a heap manager that is geared for safety, not performance, and can detect some common problems, such as some memory write overruns or underruns, or allocating out of one arena and trying to free in a different arena.

@einpoklum Why should a heap manager know? At some low-level (e.g. the O/S boundary) it probably doesn't. But a typical implementation holds a 'secret' block of information immediately before the pointer returned by new [] and that may need to know how many objects were initialised. That isn't necessary the size of the block divided by the object size. A typical new over allocates (e.g. has minimum a allocation size) and for small objects could destruct unconstructed objects. I hope that makes sense.

"But a typical implementation holds a 'secret' block of information" <- That could very well happen at the level of the new[]/delete[] function implementations, making the lower-level heap manager component simpler. But of course there's no guarantee that would be the implementer's choice.

@einpoklum Agreed. But you're talking about manufacturing something that can safely be returned to 'delete []' that wasn't returned by 'new []' and you don't know if 'new []' at some level is 'like' calling 'new char [size]' and if so exactly what. The specification clear that what you allocate with 'new' should go back to 'delete' and the same with 'new []' and 'delete []' and similar for 'malloc()' and 'free()' (with 'realloc()' in the mix!).


Can I rely on this? That is, if I emulate new T[n] in my own code as per the above, then pass the result to a delete[] - will that be well-defined and safe?

No, this is all unspecified. The only thing that you can know for sure is that new T[n] will call operator new[] with a size argument at least as large as n*sizeof(T) and will return a pointer that has sufficient space left for the T[n] object and is suitably aligned for T. (In the case that T is unsigned char, char or std::byte there are additional alignment guarantees.) Everything else is an unspecified implementation detail.
If you are willing to rely on a specific ABI guarantee, then you may have more success, although technically still UB per standard. For example in the Itanium ABI see here for a description of when and how array cookies are used. The procedure is not as you suggest. In particular there is no cookie if T doesn't have a non-trivial destructor and the usual array deallocation function doesn't take two arguments. Also, a procedure to correct for alignment is applied and doesn't have a special case of length 1.


Tweaked the question regarding trivially-destructible types. 2. I did say "ignoring alignment". I will read the Itanium ABI about this, though. Can I check for Itanium ABI using some preprocessor definition?


@einpoklum I don't think there are any preprocessor defines. This is something that the build system usually has to be aware of because you have to know the ABI in order to be able to link with other libraries.

@einpoklum Note that being trivially-destructible is not the full condition. In certain circumstances (when the usual array deallocation function takes two arguments), the size must be stored anyway.

As a general principle avoid making assumptions about how implementations work.
If you absolutely have to and you don't have detailed specifications of the implementation you're taking risks.
Even if you do have specifications you're making your code non-portable (which may matter later and is always undesirable) and still risking implementation changes later.

In the case in hand never pass to delete [] something you didn't receive from new []' and do pass it to delete [] exactly once.
What will almost certainly not work is allocating a big array (say) and passing sections of it to delete []. What may work (but is not guaranteed and not recommended) is allocating with malloc() or low-level O/S calls (outside the standard library) and passing that to delete [].
You may want to implement a customer allocator or need to allocate raw char memory (using new [] or malloc() or whatever) and use placement new to construct objects in it and call the destructor directly when you want to dispose (or recycle) it finally releasing that 'raw' memory according to how you obtained it. You can even play games allocating memory on the stack and allow return to recover it.
Premature optimisation is the root of all evil and tuning memory management like this isn't the top of the list. But it can be useful if your algorithm is allocating and deallocating large numbers of objects.
As a specific note one cause memory churn (lots of new and delete) can be avoided by good use of swap and move semantics. They and copy elision were pretty much invented to remove redundant 'new'/copy/`delete' sequences and can result in huge improvements that are far better than optimising allocation.
What you're trying to do may be reasonable. But the way you're trying to do it is not recommended and there are safer and more portable ways to do it.
Footnote: I've ignored zero-length arrays and alignment in this answer as requested by the OP however they are both relevant to custom allocation logic if you go there.
